# Eventhandler cant find find the list I target

Tags: javascript, html, list

The event handler doesn't work on my list
When I click in the LI my div on the right side should fill up with the info inside that li

But my event handler doesn't work. Or can't find the list whenever i take it out of the onload function like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    changePage(1);
};
document.getElementById("lijst").addEventListener("click", ficheVullen);
```

Here is an example of my code and what I'm trying to do.
https://jsfiddle.net/3f5g2p7s/3/

Answer (score 2):

In your code you're setting the `className` instead of the `id` for the `li` element. You should be using this instead because you're calling `getElementById("lijst")`:

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.id = "lijst";
```

Also the function `ficheVullen` is never defined.

Comment: Can you include an updated jsfiddle to see what's still not working?